# Encryption and Decryption file in s3 using Nodejs with AWS KMS

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

I am using AWS KMS to encrypt file to s3 bucket. I'm currently doing this using the AWS console, but I'd like to do this using Nodejs.

I just checked some of the things but I am not getting any clear idea about the encryption and decryption using nodejs for KMS.

Answer (score 7):

You need to take a look at the [AWS SDK for javascript](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/KMS.html). From the examples:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var kms = new AWS.KMS({apiVersion: '2014-11-01'});
 
var params = {
  KeyId: "1234abcd-12ab-34cd-56ef-1234567890ab", // The identifier of the CMK to use for encryption. You can use the key ID or Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the CMK, or the name or ARN of an alias that refers to the CMK.
  Plaintext: <Binary String>// The data to encrypt.
 };

kms.encrypt(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
   /*
   data = {
    CiphertextBlob: <Binary String>, // The encrypted data (ciphertext).
    KeyId: "arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:111122223333:key/1234abcd-12ab-34cd-56ef-1234567890ab"// The ARN of the CMK that was used to encrypt the data.
   }
   */
});

var params = {
  CiphertextBlob: <Binary String>// The encrypted data (ciphertext).
 };
 
kms.decrypt(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
   /*
   data = {
    KeyId: "arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:111122223333:key/1234abcd-12ab-34cd-56ef-1234567890ab", // The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the CMK that was used to decrypt the data.
    Plaintext: <Binary String>// The decrypted (plaintext) data.
   }
   */
});
```

Here is the link for the [aws-sdk package on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk).
Here is the link for the [main AWS SDK for Javascript documentation page](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/sdk-for-javascript/).

Comment: thanks for your reply @jeff. Can you please tell how can we encrypt and decrypt file using this method. Is it possible with aws-sdk. Can you please give the example of encryption and decryption for a file

Comment: @Team Sorry, I don't know this API that well. Please take a look at the links I provided. There are very good examples in those pages. You can do nearly everything with the `aws-sdk` that you can do with the AWS Console.

Comment: What to do for binary strings longer than 6144?

Comment: I am having trouble figuring out how to represent the binary string.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete example on how to encrypt and decrypt using AWS KMS:

```js
// Imports
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const helper = require('./helper');

AWS.config.update({ region: 'eu-west-3' })

// Declare local variables
const kms = new AWS.KMS();

helper.getTextFile('./test.txt')
.then(buffer => encryptData(buffer))
.then(encryptedData => helper.saveBlobToFile(encryptedData))
.then(data => helper.getTextFile('./encryptedTxt.txt'))
.then(buffer => decryptData(buffer))
.then(plainText => helper.saveBlobToFile(plainText)) // plaintext
.catch(console.log);

function encryptData(buffer) {
    const params = {
        KeyId: 'your key id',
        Plaintext: buffer
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        kms.encrypt(params, (err, data) => {
            if(err) reject(err);
            else resolve(data.CiphertextBlob);
        })
    })
}

function decryptData(buffer) {
    const params = {
        CiphertextBlob: buffer
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        kms.decrypt(params, (err, data) => {
            if(err) reject(err);
            else resolve(data.Plaintext);
        })
    })
}
```

Helper methods are here:

```js
const glob = require('glob')
const fs = require('fs')


function getTextFile(filePath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(filePath, (err, data) => {
            if(err) reject(err);
            else {
                resolve(data); 
            }
        });
    })
}


function saveBlobToFile(blob) {
    var buffer = Buffer.from(blob, 'base64'); // decode
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.writeFile('encryptedTxt.txt', buffer, (err) => {
            if(err) reject(err);
            else resolve('file saved correctly');
        })
    })
}

module.exports = {
    getTextFile,
    saveBlobToFile
}
```

Comment: what code changes should we make to encrypt and decrypt a video file ?

Comment: I think it should work the same way using the above code